# Rails hashes with unknown keys and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application that stores a serialized hash in a field called `properties`.

The hashes keys are unknown though, so I don't know of a way to allow this with strong parameters.

When googling, I found this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454, but I couldn't figure out exactly what a solution would be.

So basically, my question is: How can you configure strong parameters to allow hashes with unknown keys?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Ehm, don't use strong parameters then? I mean, aren't they useless in this case?

Comment: You may update the accepted answer to @jpwynn

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not really useless in this case, because he wants to permit the attribute 'properties' itself (and ignore the fact that it itself is a hash with unknown keys). So he wants to permit/whitelist that parameter, not its children.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your need is completely opposite of **objective of strong parameter**, 
when we define strong parameter then basically we are going to whitelist the coming params.

and here in your case we exactly don't know the keys, so **there is no need to put strong parameter check over there. that will solve your problem**.

Answer (score 7):

I recently had this same issue and I solved it using @fxn's method from https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454

For product with `properties` as hash, solved it as

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:properties] = params[:product][:properties]
  end
end
```

If you use `:raise` instead of `:log` for `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` in your `environment` then remember to remove `properties` from `params` before calling `permit`. Then the method will be

```
def product_params
  properties = params[:product].delete(:properties)
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:properties] = properties
  end
end
```

Comment: The missing ingredient: using `delete` to remove the hash data from params first

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers worked for me (using Rails 4.2.4), so I figured out the following workaround:

`def product_params
  properties_keys = params[:product][:properties].keys
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, properties: properties_keys)
end`

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Helped a lot! Though in Rails 5 needed to use strings, not symbols eg: params['product']['properties'].keys

Comment: great answer this works for 5.0.2 with @jpwynn's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash instead of a symbol and define what sub-properties are allowed.
This can be seen in the source here:

```
case filter
when Symbol, String
  permitted_scalar_filter(params, filter)
when Hash
  hash_filter(params, filter)
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bdc73a438a97f2e0aceeb745f4a95f95514c4aa6/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L522

e.g.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :description, :age, properties: [:key, :value])
end
```

If you have no idea what is going to be in `properties` you could use [.slice](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice). Note this will accept anything nested in any of the other fields too.

e.g.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:person).slice(:name, :description, :age, :properties) 
end
```

These approaches will work on the following params:

```
{
  "person": {
    "name": "John",
    "description": "has custom_attributes",
    "age": 42,
    "properties": [
      {
        "key": "the key",
        "value": "the value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've confirmed these will work on `Rails 4.2.6`